# Make element unchangable from angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to make my element uneditable from any source, including angular or javascript. Here is my attempt:

```
<td>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#suppliername").each(function () {
      $(this).attr("readonly", "1");
    });
  </script>
  <div id="suppliername" 
    readonly bind-once data-strat-form-control 
    data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="true" 
    data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[4].htmlName)" 
    data-strat-model="contract" 
    data-field="(contract.hasOwnProperty('COMMIT_CONTRACT')) ? contract.fields[5] : contract.fields[4]">
  </div>
</td>
```

But even using all of this the 2 way data binding is chanaging this field when I don't want it too.

How do I make this div unchangeable?

Comment: You understand that in this day and age of browsers having built in debuggers that making anything unchangable is very very difficult, no?

Comment: @Taplar Yes, I don't need a bulletproof solution. If it works as long as you don't use a browser debugger It's fine.

Comment: Why not just use one-way binding then? And why are you mixing Angular and jQuery?

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm using bind-once on the elements but it's not working. Maybe I shouldn't mix, have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, use only Angular :) But I don't understand the problem. Without dev tools, it's impossible to change the content of a div or any other non-input element anyway, sooo... what's the problem? And anyway #2, it's impossible to secure the front-end because all code sent to the browser is necessarily public. All security and checks must always be done by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` is already unchangeable. If, by unchangeable, you mean clicking on it and not being able to type any text into it, then a div already meets your criteria. If you mean unchangeable, as in, unable to update the inner text of the DOM element using javascript, there is no such property.

This `readonly` attribute is reserved for text controls (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-readonly).

If your custom directives add `input` elements that need to be dynamically marked as `readonly` (easily done with `ngReadonly`), we would need to be able to see that code, to better answer your question.